# Selected wrong keymap, how do I change it?

Tags: customization, shortcut

I had just gotten Blender 2.8 Beta and I clicked the button to continue using the Blender 2.79 shortcuts by mistake. I want to undo that. Load Factory Settings does not work. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Edit >>>> Preferences >>> Keymap

In the center you will see a dropdown menu that says Blender 27x, Change that to Blender.

[image]

Hope that helps

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you, but the Keymap is blank.

Comment: If you are using windows, put this in your file browser :

%APPDATA%\Blender Foundation\Blender

Once there, find the userpref and delete it or just cut it , and then, open blender again